# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseIsDown' of undefined

Tags: highcharts, console, bar-chart

I am getting an error in console when I try to reload the chart on click of a button. Cant figure out why.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseIsDown' of undefined
```

I have created a jsfiddle for the same. The first click will draw the chart and on second click although it redraws the chart but there is a error in console.

Note: JSFiddle is just to replicate the situation I am facing.

http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/xpy0Lbma/4/

Comment: It's a bug in 4.2.2 version. Already fixed in the master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/xpy0Lbma/6/

Comment: @PawełFus thanks for updating me. I could not find the mention of the bug anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Use latest branch from Master will resolve this issue. I have tested and it worked as expected.
Reference page: https://code.highcharts.com/
CDN: https://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js